# Why do I have to repair my booting when swapping harddrives in my laptop?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I bought a new SSD for my Lenovo Thinkpad W530 (I am not sure if hadware is relevant). I installed 15.04 on the new SSD in EFI-only mode with manual partitioning (`/efi`, `/` and `/home` partitions, bootloader installed to /efi).

So far, so good. I then tried to insert my old drive because I wanted to copy some files on an external drive and then a new ssd drive. To my dismay, it refused to boot. I had to install repair-boot which solved the problem. I then inserted my new SSD and it againd refused to boot. Again, repair-boot solved it. What is going on? Is something written to some circuits on the motherboard in the laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much. EFI-mode booting involves two things:

- Boot loader files written to the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) on the hard disk.
- Pointers to the ESP-based files stored in NVRAM on the motherboard.

The intent is that you can install as many boot loaders as you like and provide an order in which the computer should try them. Users should also be able to override that order using their computers' built-in boot manager. In principle, this should greatly simplify multi-boot configurations.

Unfortunately, many computers delete NVRAM entries that point to devices that aren't available when the computer boots. Thus, when you swap disks, you can lose the ability to boot from them. IMHO, this is a design flaw in EFI.

Fortunately, there is a relatively easy workaround, but it requires some foresight to implement: In addition to the stored boot loader locations, a special one exists: `EFI\BOOT\boot{arch}.efi`, where `{arch}` is an architecture code -- normally `x64` for x86-64 (AMD64) systems. This location is tried if no other boot entry works. It's normally used on removable media, but most EFIs will use it as a fallback for hard disks, too. Thus, if you copy GRUB or some other valid boot loader to `EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` on the ESP (normally `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` in Ubuntu), the disk will remain bootable even if the EFI boot entries are deleted. Note that you may need to copy boot loader configuration and support files, too.

FWIW, Fedora's got a boot loader called `fallback.efi` that's designed to restore deleted NVRAM entries. I've not looked into it in depth, but putting it in the `EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` location *should* fix this problem, too. The last I heard, though, some (broken) EFIs cause this file to run on every boot, and the result is an ever-increasing number of boot entries. This bug may well have been fixed by now, but I've not checked up on it recently.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation (and your very helpful pages here: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html )!

I needed to issue

    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi/
    cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/boot/bootx64.efi

and the drive started to work on swapping. There was another booloader  in `/boot/efi/boot/bootx64.efi` before, I wonder what that was, probably something Repair boot left there.